# That is house of my brother's classmate

Tags: apostrophe

Which one is correct to say?

> That is my brother's classmate house.
>
> That is my brother's classmate's house.

What's the grammar rule behind this? What's the correct use of apostrophe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second sentence is correct. You need to add the apostrophe **’s**  after the word “classmate”. However, you could also say:

> That house belongs to a classmate of my brother’s.